# Как слить два коммита в одной ветке?

Tags: git

В репозитории `GitHub'а` имеется несколько коммитов на одной ветке `master`. Удалил функционал, про который думал, что он не пригодится. Но оказалось, что он всё-таки нужен, но уже успел сделать несколько коммитов.

Как вернуть в ветку удаленный код, не потеряв наработки из последних коммитов?

Comment: Давайте уточним. А новые комиты вам нужны?

Comment: @RazGalstyan конечно. Последний абзац на это указывает)

Comment: @Александр Видел, как я понял они обсуждают уменьшение количество коммитов в ветке путем их объединения.

Answer (score 0):

Первым шагом создайте новую ветку.

```
git checkout -b <имяветки>
```

Потом перейдите на ветку `maset`.

```
git checkout master
```

После этих шагов у вас уже есть последние коммиты во отдельной ветке. И вы их не потеряете.

Дальше нужно откатить ветку `master` на тот коммит на которой ваши старые данные.

Для этого надо узнать хеш код того самого коммита. А потом уже этой коммандой изменить состояние ветки `master` на указанный коммит. К примеру хеш код этот `0d1d7fc32`.

```
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
```

И на последнем этапе уже `merge`

```
git merge <Имя ранее созданной ветки>.
```

Можно еще так.

```
git checkout <commitID>

git checkout -b <newBranchName>

<edit file to make an inconsequential change>

git commit -a -m "creating a branch to merge from"

git checkout master

git merge <newBranchName>

<edit file to resolve conflicts>

git commit -a
```

Comment: Fast-forward, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @ИванАнтонов Как не изменилось, после каждой команды вы уверены ветки изменились? в консоли все показывает.

Comment: Он просто перекинул меня с коммита с удаленным функционалом на последний коммит без него. Я в консоле вижу какие изменения произошли. Я ожидал что мне придется вручную выбирать то, что мне нужно.

Comment: Updating 917a211..dc4374e 
Fast-forward 
3 files changed, 58 insertions(+), 41 deletions(-)

Comment: @ИванАнтонов Что показывает после последней команды `merge`?

Comment: Сообщением выше ответ на этот вопрос. Я уже по всякому пробовал. Все равно он просто возвращается к последнему коммиту. Наверно нет возможности в одной ветке мержить.

Comment: @ИванАнтонов А эти файлы уже не последние апдейты на старом коммите? вы говорите не понятное

Comment: Последний коммит это коммит, который я сделал в последний раз, т.е. он самый молодой.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72608/discussion-between-raz-galstyan-and--).